# What does LOC and ACC mean in perl?

Tags: perl

For filling content of file in perl there are several ways. And two of them are followings:

1.

```
print $file_handle1 <<LOC
this is content of first file
LOC
;
```

2.

```
print $file_handle2 <<ACC
this is content of second file
ACC
;
```

So what is the difference (if there are any) between `LOC` and `ACC`?

Comment: Your semicolons are at a dangerous postion, in general put them at the end of the line (like iin the answer by Mat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are just names, they do exactly the same thing. You can use anything you want there.

This syntax is called [here documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), and it's not specific to perl.

```
print <<HELLO;
Good Bye
HELLO
```

Comment: This was news for me. Thank you @Mat!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any difference (at least as far as Perl is concerned). That is [heredoc syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators), you can use any value as the end of block indicator.

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean anything. They are delimiters for multi-line text.

For more information, Google [perl here-doc](http://www.google.ca/search?q=perl+here-doc).